# Rails Puzzling Database Issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am facing a really puzzling issue in my rail's application. This issue almost never happens but it did happen one time last week.
I have a controller method which is to update certains models:

```
def updateModels
    #some logic here
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      #1 @model1.profiles.destroy_all
      #2 @model1.profiles << @profiles
      #3 @model1.reset_profile_members
      #4 @model1.save!
    end
end
```

Almost all the times the above code works perfectly and all updates #1 #2 #3 are performed seamlessly. However last week we encountered a scenario in which update #1 and #2 happened and update #3 did not. I am a bit puzzled since everything is in a transaction this should not happen. My database is MySQL. 
Any thoughts on what can be the potential issues here ?

Comment: How do you update those models, i.e. what method do you use?

Comment: Thanks. Updates are done in usual manner. Firstly modifying properties and then calling save. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Could you show us what's going on within transaction block?

Comment: You need to show the code within the transaction block. "Updates are done in the usual manner" could mean one of many ways of doing updates to an AR instance.

Comment: Have updated the code. Can this be an issue related to multi-threads synchronization ?. Example, first thread updates #1 and #2 and then second thread comes in and updates #1 #2 and #3. Now thread 1 comes back and updates #3. Hence we have updates #1 and #2 from Thread 2 while update #3 is from Thread 1. Can this happen ?

Comment: What's in that reset_profiles_members method ?

Comment: What is the engine type of the mysql table? Note that MyISAM does not support transactions.